# Coloring videos to give bright colors

Tags: color-correction

I am new to video editing and would like to know how to color my videos like the professionals do. I can always tell the difference between an amateur video shot with a Handycam and a professional movie, and I think part of that difference is in the coloring. I have a screenshot from a video with beautiful coloring, and I would like to apply it to my family videos. Is there a simple way to do this?[image: Perfect color correction 1]

Comment: What are you shooting on & currently editing in? Do you have an example still you could show us for comparison? You can do colour grading in most editing suites these days. Personally I think your example shot is a little hyper-real, but at least it looks 'cheerful'.

Comment: Can I kind of extract color grading from a sample shot like this?

Comment: Mehdi - as Tetsujin asked, what are you using. Hardware and editing platform. Please show us what your current results are, otherwise we cannot help.